# Django auth ldap is not updating users database

Tags: python, django, ldap

When I login using django_auth_ldap the user name, last, email isnt populated. If i check the admin nothing populates. I check the AD logs they seem fine. I not sure why its not populating. I did a packet capture on the LDAP query I do see the proper info in the results, my name, email, etc. Not sure whats going here, any help or ideas would be appreciated.

settings.py

```
# Populate the Django user from the LDAP directory
AUTH_LDAP_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}
```

Log capture...

```
2013-11-08 10:01:14,999 DEBUG search_s('DC=MYDC,DC=com', 2, '(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)') returned 1 objects: cn=stager\, stager,ou=users,ou=cdp,dc=MYDC,dc=com
2013-11-08 10:01:15,059 DEBUG Populating Django user stager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUTH_LDAP_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP == AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP

to many "LDAP"s broke the argument....

Comment: Similarly, I failed to notice I had ```AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP``` defined in two places in my settings--couldn't figure out why some of the fields weren't populating.